# Mergesort performance in C

Tags: performance, c, mergesort

I have two questions about my code:

1. Are there any performance improvements in this implementation or generally (`register int` ?) that I could make?
2. What could I improve in my coding style?

```
void mergesortArray(int data[], int amount){

    if(amount == 1) return;

    //Precomputing values
    int sizeint = sizeof(int);
    int amountLeft = amount / 2;
    int amountRight = (amount % 2 == 0) ? amountLeft : (amountLeft + 1);

    //Splitting the array in right and left
    int *left = calloc(amountLeft, sizeint);
    int *right = calloc(amountRight, sizeint);
    if(left == NULL || right == NULL) return;

    //Copying the splitted content
    memcpy(left, data, amountLeft * sizeint);
    memcpy(right, data + amountLeft, amountRight * sizeint);

    //Recursive sorting the splitted arrays
    mergesortArray(left,amountLeft);
    mergesortArray(right,amountRight);

    //Merging the numbers
    int *pos1 = &left[0];
    int *pos2 = &right[0];
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
        if(*pos1 <= *pos2) {
            data[i] = *pos1;
            if (pos1 == &right[amountRight - 1])
                break;
            if(pos1 == &left[amountLeft - 1])
                pos1 = &right[amountRight - 1];
            else
                pos1++;
        }
        else {
            data[i] = *pos2;
            if(pos2 == &right[amountRight - 1])
                pos2 = &left[amountLeft - 1];
            else
                pos2++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: in a modern C compiler, the only effect of using the `register` modifier is that the address of the variable cannot be acquired.  I.E. a total waste of effort.

Comment: the posted code will have a very large recursion level for any data set, where the recursion level has a direct relationship to the size of the data set.   Each recursion is calling `calloc()` twice, but there is no calls to `free()`  so this algorithm will leak memory like a sieve.

Comment: The code seems to be performing the merge at every exit from a lower level recursion.   That seems like way to many merges.

Comment: The posted code could call `free()` for each of the pointers from the two local calls to `calloc()` just before returning from the recursion level

Comment: perhaps could eliminate any calls to `calloc()` and `free()` by sorting/merging the sub arrays in place rather than copying them and sorting the copies

Comment: Un-requested functional improvement: `if(amount == 1) return;` --> `if(amount <= 1) return;`  Might as well catch pathological cases too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `register` keyword will do nothing. Current day compilers are smart enough to find a good register allocation themselves without you running in its way.

Why `calloc`? you initialize the values through `memcpy` anyway so no need for the zero initialization, `malloc` will work fine. Speaking of you need to free what you allocate otherwise you'll get a memory leak.

You should only need to allocate a single extra array for the merge.

When the amount left to sort is small (`amount < 5`) you can switch over to another sort that is more efficient for small numbers like insertion sort.

Finally brace position on your else is a bit odd:

```
    if(*pos1 <= *pos2) {

    }
    else {

    }
```

I'd expect either the opening braces to also be on its own line or else to be on the same as the closing brace of the if.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "The amount left to sort"?

Answer (score 1):

You can optimize `calloc`s away by allocating a buffer of equal size and contents as the input array `data` at the very beginning of sorting. After that, you keep alternating the roles of the two arrays (`data` and the buffer). See what I mean:

```
static void mergesortArrayImprovedImpl(int* source, 
                                       int* target, 
                                       size_t offset, 
                                       size_t length) 
{
    if (length < 2) return;

    size_t left_range_length = length >> 1;

    // Divide.
    mergesortArrayImprovedImpl(target, 
                               source, 
                               offset, 
                               left_range_length);

    mergesortArrayImprovedImpl(target, 
                               source, 
                               offset + left_range_length, 
                               length - left_range_length);

    // Conquer.
    size_t left_index = offset;
    size_t left_index_bound = offset + left_range_length;
    size_t right_index = left_index_bound;
    size_t right_index_bound = offset + length;
    size_t target_index = offset;

    while (left_index < left_index_bound && right_index < right_index_bound) 
    {
        target[target_index++] = source[left_index] < source[right_index] ?
                                 source[left_index++] :
                                 source[right_index++];
    }

    memcpy(target + target_index, 
           source + left_index, 
           sizeof(int) * (left_index_bound - left_index));

    memcpy(target + target_index,
           source + right_index,
           sizeof(int) * (right_index_bound - right_index));
}

void mergesortArrayImproved(int data[], size_t amount) 
{
    if (amount < 2) return;

    int* aux = malloc(sizeof(int) * amount);
    memcpy(aux, data, sizeof(int) * amount);
    mergesortArrayImprovedImpl(aux, data, 0, amount);
    free(aux);
}
```

I leave profiling the two implementations, however, to you.

Answer (score 0):

As usual, I recommend [*random pausing*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/378024/23771) as a way to see what takes the most time.

That said (I hate saying "that said" because it implies guessing is a good thing - it's not) here's my strong suspicion:
A call to `calloc` only takes a line of code. Does that mean it's cheap?
If you single-step it in the disassembly window you'd better bring lunch, because it will take quite a while.
So I suspect the samples will show that as your "bottleneck".

You don't really need any extra memory (as @ratchet said) except another temporary array of the same size as the original.
You can do your splitting in the original array.
Do the merge into the temporary array, and copy back to the original array.
That way you `malloc` only once.
(And you should probably `free` it when you're done.)

And also as @ratchet said, when you get down to small `amount`, an unrolled bubble sort would probably be faster.
Example:

```
if (amount == 1){
} else if (amount == 2){
    if (data[0] > data[1]) swap(data[0], data[1]);
} else if (amount == 3){
    if (data[0] > data[1]) swap(data[0], data[1]);
    if (data[0] > data[2]) swap(data[0], data[2]);
    if (data[1] > data[2]) swap(data[1], data[2]);
} else if (amount == 4){
    if (data[0] > data[1]) swap(data[0], data[1]);
    if (data[0] > data[2]) swap(data[0], data[2]);
    if (data[0] > data[3]) swap(data[0], data[3]);
    if (data[1] > data[2]) swap(data[1], data[2]);
    if (data[1] > data[3]) swap(data[1], data[3]);
    if (data[2] > data[3]) swap(data[2], data[3]);
} else {
    ... your code ...
}
```

BTW: You could say:

```
int amountRight = amount - amountLeft;
```

Comment: Do you know `switch`?

Comment: @Deduplicator: Sure, but the only purpose of `switch` is to give the compiler permission to generate a jump table, and it only does that if the number of branches is sufficiently large, and the branch codes are compact. Otherwise it just generates an if-ladder.